# Using Angular JS NG-Idle

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I am using AngularJS custom directive developed by HackedByChinese called [ng-idle](https://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng-idle/).

When ever any AJAX call is made, GET, POST etc, will this directive by default reset its timeout timer until the AJAX request is completed? Or will it calculate the time out even though the AJAX call is in process?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [this](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng-idle/wiki/Idle-and-Idleprovider) link for more details. Basically, you can set up on which events timeout timer gets reset. If you want to postpone resetting action unit AJAX call is finished, try out `Keepalive` service to postpone the timeout reset.